# Paypal REST API giving 401 error when moving to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paypal

We're trying to use Paypal's REST API in Ruby on Rails, it worked perfectly in sandbox.
When we moved to production, it all of a sudden doesn't work. Here's the logs from heroku:

```
Started POST "/transfer/payments/start_payment" for 77.127.249.103 at 2015-12-09 21:05:37 +0000
2015-12-09T21:05:37.709999+00:00 app[web.1]: Request[post]: https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
2015-12-09T21:05:38.383206+00:00 app[web.1]: Response[401]: Unauthorized, Duration: 0.673s
2015-12-09T21:05:38.396230+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-09T21:05:38.396233+00:00 app[web.1]: PayPal::SDK::Core::Exceptions::UnauthorizedAccess (Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.  Response debug ID = 9287826b548af.):
2015-12-09T21:05:38.396234+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/transfer/payments_controller.rb:23:in `start_payment'
2015-12-09T21:05:38.396234+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-09T21:05:38.396235+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-09T21:05:38.394396+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1020ms (ActiveRecord: 23.9ms)
2015-12-09T21:05:38.394396+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1020ms (ActiveRecord: 23.9ms)
```

Our code is:

```
def start_payment
            @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
            @paypal_payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.new({
                :intent => "sale",
                :payer => {
                :payment_method => "paypal" },
                :redirect_urls => {
                :return_url => root_url + transfer_payments_path,
                :cancel_url => "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/ruby?cancel=true" },
                :transactions => [ {
                    :amount => {
                    :total => sprintf('%.2f', @payment.amount),
                    :currency => "USD" 
                    },
                    :description => "Bounty Balance" 
                    } ]              
                })
            @paypal_payment.create

            index = @paypal_payment.links.find_index {|item| item.rel == "approval_url"}
            link = @paypal_payment.links[index]
            redirect_to link.href
        end
```

We checked on paypal.com, and we have green checkmarks next to the relevant services in paypal- the only things we don't have are direct credit cards, future payments, and payouts.

Anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Paypal is really difficult to work with, API wise. My company eventually switched to [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) which only took an hour to implement.

Comment: Haven't used the Paypal API before, but have you switched out the URLs? Sometimes APIs have a url for development and different one for production. Same for API keys. Also, check your `config/development.rb` and make sure any necessary Paypal API configurations are also in `config/production.rb` as well.

Comment: Nope... not the issue, checked both

Comment: Did you set all your environment variables in Heroku?

Comment: when you switch to Live, did you change your credentials to Live one as well? The error seems to be coming from token's endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I did. It's live